# Code in C that has the user input 10 numbers and outputs them in a certain order

Tags: c

Write a program that reads 10 integers and prints the first and the last on
one line, the second and the ninth on the next line, the third and the seventh
on the next line, and so forth.

```
 Please enter 10 numbers:
10 31 2 73 24 65 6 87 18 9

Your numbers are:
10 9
31 18
 2 87
73 6
24 65
```

So far I have written code that ask for the input. I do not know how to get the output and can not find the answer anywhere at the moment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int numbers;

    printf("Please enter Ten numbers:");
    scanf("%d", & numbers);

    printf("your numbers are: %d", numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you can read and print 1 number. Can you improve your code to read and print 2 numbers?

Comment: So in order for my code to print two numbers, do I have to input %2d?  within my scanf? I am very new to programming and I still have yet to understand how to speak to my system.

Comment: The code can be improved to read two numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to C, Don! There are many ways to approach this, but let's stick with your array utilization....

1) set the input into an array

2) If you could ensure your input would be 10 values.

```
for (i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for j=9; j > 4; j--)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", array[i], array[j]);
    }
}
```

- "i" is set to zero since the first index location in an array is actually array[0] (not array[1])

You can ***increment*** the value of "i" while **decrementing** the value of "j", so are working towards the center. Makes sense?

Comment: I did some research on what you are talking about and it makes sense. Just one last question. Why would J=9? I can see that you are decreasing it by the increment of 1. Doing it this way allows the system to map out towards the center correct?

Comment: If you set j=9 and then say array[j], you are saying "hey computer, go to index 9 of my array (since computer start indexing at 0, this is the 10th item). The system doesn't map it out; you are explicitly telling it where/how to decrement by saying j-- (this means with each loop, decrease the value of j by one). So that the next tiem you loop, you are saying "hey computer, print out the index 8 of my array" and so on and so forth ;) Make sense?

Comment: Yup! I get it now lol sorry I am pretty much a dummy when it comes to this. I am starting from the basics. Thank you I really appreciate it!

Comment: Don, no need to bash yourself/your understanding. I recommend C Programming Book by Kochan as well as K&R after that ;) You got this!!!